# Java GridBagLayout + Absolute Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, null-layout-manager

I am trying to make a 3 column layout, in each column i want to be able to absolute position labels and textboxes.

Problem is that my label (jLabel2) never even gets displayed..

Here is my code:

```
 /**
  * Top JPanel (Top) 
  */
 JPanel pnlTop = new JPanel();
 pnlTop.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(223, 223, 217));
 pnlTop.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, new java.awt.Color(173, 173, 166)));
 c.gridx = 0;
 c.gridy = 0;
 c.gridwidth = 5; // five rows
 c.gridheight = 1; // one column
 c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
 //c.weighty = 0.04;
 add(pnlTop, c);       

 /**
  * Top JPanel Content (Here is where i want to put absolute content)
  */
 JPanel pnlTopContent = new JPanel();
 pnlTopContent.setLayout(null);

 jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
 jLabel2.setText("Hello");

 jLabel2.setLocation(150, 50);     

 pnlTopContent.add(jLabel2);
 pnlTop.add(pnlTopContent);
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `pnlTopContent` visible?

Comment: Something's missing. You don't show creating jLabel2. Also don't use absolute layout, not even for a part of the UI. Use an appropriate layout manager instead

Comment: Yea, its so strange why nothing is showing :/

Comment: Im creating the label like this: jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

Comment: Try without setting null layout manager for pnlTopContent.

Comment: Then its showing but not in the right place

Comment: 1) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Answer (score 1):

> Then its showing but not in the right place

What does "right place" mean to you? Why are you even adding you label to a second panel? Why not just add the label directly to the pnlTopContent?

GridBagLayout has a constraint that allows you to position the component right/left/center of the column. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). You might want to start with the `anchor` constraint.

Comment: I assumed the labels might not coincide with the rest of the grid since the width was set to 5, but if they do then this is obviously the simplest implementation. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use layout manager for `pnlTopContent`. Which one is right depends on what you want. Even the default `FlowLayout` might work. If you want to center the label, you can for example use `FlowLayout` with center alignment:

```
pnlTopContent.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

Comment: There is no need to use HTML to center text. `For a label that occupies the entire pnlTopContent...` - The easiest solution is to  use a FlowLayout with center alignment. In other cases you might use  `label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER)`

Comment: @camicr Very true, I'll edit the answer. Of course, centering is just a guess anyway